# I am getting this error when using apt-get command

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, permissions

```
mayank@mayank-Compaq-15-Notebook-PC:~$ apt-get install android-tools-adb
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: try with `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb`

Answer (score 2):

```
are you root?
```

Did you run the command with `sudo` before `apt-get`? Sudo allows you to launch commands with root privileges, which are needed to manage programs.

Your command should look something like this

```
sudo apt-get install
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove
```